# XSLT: Using xsl:value-of - am I returning a string or a nodeset of individual strings?

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I have a template that splits strings at a given separator:

```
<xsl:template name="SplitStringAtSeparator">
  <xsl:param name="stringToSplit"/>
  <xsl:param name="separatorCharacter" />
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="SplitStringAtSeparator">
           <xsl:with-param name="stringToSplit"
                           select="substring-after($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="$stringToSplit != ''">
           <xsl:value-of select="$stringToSplit"/>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Assuming `stringToSplit` = '**hello this is a string to split**' and we're splitting on the space character, am I going to get back a single text node that just leaves out the space characters

```
hellothisisastringtosplit
```

or am I going to get a nodeset of text nodes that I can iterate through?

```
node[1] = hello
node[2] = this
node[3] = is
node[4] = a 
node[5] = string 
node[6] = to 
node[7] = split
```

I should note that if the latter is not the case, *the latter is what I'm trying to do*.

Comment: How do you use this spreadsheet and this template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us say your input document is ....

```
<root>
  <stringToSplit>hello this is a string to split</stringToSplit>
</root>
```

... and you want to split the string content of `stringToSplit` and process the particles. Let us say the processing is just output a numbered list of the particles. Here are two examples of how you could do it. One solution is in XSLT 1.0, an the other in XSLT 2.

### XSLT 1.0 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363330"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="so exsl">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" doctype-system="" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello! This is a string to split.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello! This is a string to split.</h1>
      <p>The following is an example of splitting a string in XSLT 1.0 and then processing each string part.</p>
      <h2>String parts</h2>
      <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/stringToSplit" />
      </ol>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="SplitStringAtSeparator">
  <xsl:param name="stringToSplit" />
  <xsl:param name="separatorCharacter" />
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)">
       <so:particle><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)"/></so:particle>
       <xsl:call-template name="SplitStringAtSeparator">
         <xsl:with-param name="stringToSplit" select="substring-after($stringToSplit, $separatorCharacter)" />
         <xsl:with-param name="separatorCharacter" select="$separatorCharacter" />
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="$stringToSplit">
       <so:particle><xsl:value-of select="$stringToSplit"/></so:particle>
     </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stringToSplit">
  <xsl:variable name="split-string">
    <xsl:call-template name="SplitStringAtSeparator">
      <xsl:with-param name="stringToSplit" select="text()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="separatorCharacter" select="' '" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set( $split-string)" mode="particle-processing" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="so:particle" mode="particle-processing">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XSLT 2 Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" doctype-system="" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
      <title>Hello! This is a string to split.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello! This is a string to split.</h1>
      <p>The following is an example of splitting a string in XSLT 2 and then processing each string part.</p>
      <h2>String parts</h2>
      <ol>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="root/stringToSplit/text()" regex="\S*">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
      </ol>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

In both cases you get output document like ...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Hello! This is a string to split.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello! This is a string to split.</h1>
    <p>The following is an example of splitting a string in XSLT 1.0 and then processing each string part.</p>
    <h2>String parts</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>this</li>
      <li>is</li>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>string</li>
      <li>to</li>
      <li>split</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using XSLT 1.0. It is not possible to create a node-set of (only) text nodes in XSLT 1.0 (or in XML in general). If you want to address your tokens individually, you must create them as XML elements.

An additional complication with XSLT 1.0 is that the result will initially be a *result-tree-fragment*, not a *node-set*. You must use the extension `node-set()` function (which practically all XSLT 1.0 processors support) to convert it a node-set. Only then you will be able to address each node by its position.

Comment: To elaborate on this: each xsl:value-of instruction writes a text node to the result tree. The only way to capture these text nodes is to use an xsl:variable, which (a) constructs a result tree fragment that can only be accessed using the node-set() function, and (b) in doing so, concatenates adjacent text nodes into a single text node. As you may already know, it all gets much easier with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: As I understand it, the Visual Studio team has no plans to integrate XSLT 2.0.  Is there a Nuget package or something I can use to get to 2.0?  Right now I'm stuck using VS, and thereby stuck in 1.0.